# odoo 10 Many2one DropdownView change number of items

Tags: odoo, one-to-many, odoo-10

How can I change the number of visible items in the dropdownlist?

model:

```
category = fields.Many2one('my.category', 'Category', required=True)
```

view usage inside form:

```
<field name="category" options="{'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True}"/>
```

I just have 9 categories to display & the dropdown list only shows 7 categories + the 'Search more'. 
[image]

It would be nice to show all categories, if necessary with a scroll bar.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `<field name="category" widget="selection"` /> allows me to show all categories. The disadvantage is, searching is not possible and creating and editing categories is disabled also. I might use it though, unless someone can present me a solution how to override the CompletionFieldMixin.

Answer (score 2):

if yout want to change limit in dropdown view, you can find in web->static->src->js->view_from.js. and change the limit  values for show many2one list.

create file new_widget.js:

```
(function() {
      var instance = openerp;
      var _t = instance.web._t,
      _lt = instance.web._lt;
      var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;


     instance.web.form.CompletionFieldMixin = {
         init: function() {
         this.limit = 10;
         this.orderer = new instance.web.DropMisordered();

     },};})();
```

and write in xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="MyModule assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyModule/static/src/js/new_widget.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I found the mixin and the use of it in var FieldMany2One. Unfortunately, I have not much experience in javascript, or how odoo is using it. Can you please tell me how I can inherit the mixin and how to use it in my many2one field?

Comment: I found the application [web_m2x_options](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/web_m2x_options/). The developers describe that the additional option 'limit' is added to the many2one field - exactly what I'm looking for. However, it's for Odoo9. Installing it for Odoo10 did not throw any errors, but it did not work either :(
any suggestions?

Comment: I copied your code, changed the src path to the script inside the xml to match my project and added the xml to the manifest inside data : []. Still the dropdown shows only 7 items. Any suggestions what I'm still missing? Did you test your code for Odoo10?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works well for V14: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/web_m2x_options/